# WindowsForms losing highlighted state after programmatic right click

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, low-level

I am implementing a software that lets (disabled) users navigate Windows through mouse clicks only. For this purpose I have a radar that is drawn along the screen edges to the current cursor Position.

Probably it is worth mentioning, that my window is totally clickthrough via:

```
#region Make window totally clickthrough
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x80000 /* WS_EX_LAYERED */ | 0x20 /* WS_EX_TRANSPARENT */ | 0x80/* WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW */ | 0x08000000 /* WS_EX_NOACTIVATE */;
        return cp;
    }
}
#endregion
```

When the user enters the "highlighting" state, I programmatically tell the system to start highlighting via

```
public void StartHighlighting()
{
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

then I move the cursor until highlighting is done and tell the system to stop highlighting via:

```
public void StopHighlighting()
{
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

This works like a charm. However, when I want to do a right click on for example a selected text via:

```
public void PerformRightclick()
{
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

The text loses its highlighted state before a context menu is shown. 
The `mouse_event` function comes from the user32.dll library.

Comment: This my seem like a weird question but do you know where your cursor is located when your right down is triggered? If it is not over the highlighted text in your control, such as a coordinate over another control then you might get a focus change firing before your right up is processed.

Comment: Yeah, the cursor is located above the highlighted text in the given scenario.

I have also thought about a focus change. Maybe my window gets the focus before passing through the rightclick, However, the window is configured to behave as it is not there at all (see `CreateParams` for that). So this can not be the reason.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but could a WM_SETFOCUS on the control being hovered have any impact you think? I guess it depends on if a control on a inactive window can accept focus?

Comment: Do you mean that I should send WM_SETFOCUS before performing the right click?

Comment: Or just verify that it has focus. It sounds like what is happening is that text is selected in a control and a right click is made to bring up the edit control's context menu, however, the edit control of the selected text does not have focus.